# how to convert pandas text column to nltk text object

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
publish_date    headline_text
20030219        aba decides against community broadcasting 
20030219        act fire witnesses must be aware of defamation
20030219        a g calls for infrastructure protection summit
20030219        air nz staff in aust strike for pay rise
20030219        air nz strike to affect australian travellers
```

I want to convert `headline_text` column to nltk text object in order to apply all nltk methods on it.

I am doing following, but it does not seem to work

`headline_text = nlp_df['headline_text'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
nltk_col = df.headline_text.apply(lambda row: nltk.Text(row.split(' ')))
```

To assign this column to the dataframe, you can then do:

```
df=df.assign(nltk_texts=nltk_col)
```

Then we can check the type of the first row in the new `nltk_texts` column:

```
print(type(df.nltk_texts.loc[0])) # outputs: nltk.text.Text
```

To unify all rows into a single NLTK Text object, you can do:

```
single = nltk.Text([word for row in df.headline_text for word in row.split(' ')])
```

Then `print(type(single))` will output `nltk.text.Text`.

Comment: Instead of dataframe column can we assign this in one variable?

Comment: Edited my answer, now the new column is first saved as nltk_col, a pandas.core.series.Series object. Is this what you meant?

Comment: What I want is instead of creating new column, I want to take it in one variable which is NLTK Text object, so I can perform all the NLTK methods on that corpus.

Comment: Oh ok, so unify all rows in headline_text to one single NLTK Text object, yep? A moment...

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: (see last bit :) )